# How to say '1/4 hour' and '3/4 hour' in English

Tags: word-choice

I have heard '1/2 hour' spoken as 'a half hour' and '1 hour' spoken as 'one hour', but I don't know how to say '1/4 hour' or '3/4 hour'?. So can any one tell me how to say these?

Note: I am not looking for '15 minutes' or '45 minutes'.

Comment: Use "quarter of an hour" and "three quarters of an hour".

Comment: Hi Vinothkumar, if you have any other questions about how to say things in English, the best place to ask is [ELL.se].

Comment: Thanks@Chappo, Do you know more website for learn English quick and effectively means please tell me?

Comment: One step at a time. Don't ask for more sites without even having tried the ones you've already been told. That's not efficient learning, that's no learning at all. Start my making yourself familiar with all the knowledge available to you here. Once you're done with that, you can ask for more. And never post your email address in plain text here, or on any page anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29979/how-do-i-pronounce-these-fractions http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44269/is-the-expression-1-4-of-something-or-3-4-of-something-idiomatic-natural-sou

Answer (score 2):

Ste's answer is correct ("quarter of an hour" and "three quarters of an hour") and another option is "quarter past" and "quarter of". You can read more about that convention here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-does-ten-of-six-mean-in-regard-to-time

Comment: In British English, 9:45 is usually "a quarter **to** ten" rather than "a quarter **of** ten", although the latter is occasionally heard.

Answer (score 1):

Also relevant, the expressions "top of the hour" and "bottom of the hour" refer to the next coming hour and 30 minutes past the hour respectively.